# Updating configuration when an Eclipse plugin is updated

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Does `IProjectNature.configure()` get called when an Eclipse plugin is updated? Is there a better method that will get executed when a plugin gets updated?

This information seems to be missing from the documentation I've read. Due to the lack of a similar question on SO I'm adding this even though it's easily testable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. If you need to know when your plug-in changes, store the version information in the plug-in's private state location and read it in, preferably not on the UI thread, when the plug-in activates. It would be good to know *why* you think you need to know this, since it's usually not a useful piece of information on its own.

[JavaDoc](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/Plugin.html#getStateLocation())

Comment: Agreed, it is an abnormal case. Thanks for answering. For anyone reading this, version information can be read from the manifest by using the methods within `FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass())`